# Why can't try catch the exception?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

`testtry.groovy`:

```
try {
  def giturl = repo
} catch (Exception e) {
  println e
}
```

The variable `repo` is null，it is not predictable. I want that it can be null and catch the exception.

Comment: I can’t reproduce. I ran it on https://groovy-playground.appspot.com and it _did_ catch.

Comment: There is no error in this expression if variable `repo` exists and it has null value. Add a line before `try`: `repo=null`, and groovy playground will not catch any error.